# Flutter: Is there any difference between these layouts?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In flutter, Is there any difference between these layouts? -

- Expanded
- SizedBox.expand
- BoxConstraints.expand()

If all are same, why there are multiple layout classes/functions for same functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know.

**Expanded** widget can only used inside of **Row**, **Column** and **Flex**. It helps to expand  the children based on the flex value. By default - it's 1.

**SizedBox.expand** -  It will expand the child as large as it's parent allows. You can put anywhere unlike Expanded.

**BoxConstraints.expand** - Usually takes as object of ConstrainedBox constraints property.

From the documentation -

> Creates box constraints that expand to fill another box constraints.
>
> If width or height is given, the constraints will require exactly the
> given value in the given dimension.

Comment: Thank you for answering and clearing concept.

Comment: It's my pleasure.